# Free alternative to Druva InSync?

Tags: backup

At work I have Duva InSync. It basically backs your files up to a remote server periodically (I think it also works for phones.) I've done similar things at home with batch files and rsync but I was wondering if there was a free (or at least cheap) product for home use? I don't mind what OS the server side of it runs on.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you may want to look at Microsoft's free [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) 2.1 (current version as of 11-25-2013)

> *SyncToy 2.1 is a free application that synchronizes files and folders between locations. Typical uses include sharing files, such as photos,
>   with other computers and creating backup copies of files and folders.*

Another option is the open source [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) at sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

[DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com) is free up to several gigabytes. There are multiple ways to increase the size of your initial 2GB free account.

It syncs files between multiple PCs, servers, phones, tablets, etc.

Comment: Good point, I'd prefer local storage if possible. I have an always on ESXI server.